# Windows 8.1: Behaviors on Flyouts don't Work

Tags: xaml, mvvm, behavior, windows-8.1, flyout

I am developing a windows 8.1 app using VS 2013 and MVVM Light.

The following code shows the behavior in a flyout within an appbar:

```
<AppBarButton.Flyout>
    <Flyout x:Name="FlyoutCalculator"
            Placement="Top"
            FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutPresenterBaseStyle}">

        <uc:Calculator ApplyCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                       CancelCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}"                                           
                       Available="{Binding AvailableCounter, Mode=OneWay}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Opening">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCurrentCostsCommand}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Flyout>
</AppBarButton.Flyout>
```

Unfortunately I get an exception while compiling the app:

> WinRT-Informationen: Cannot add instance of type `Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior` to a collection of type `Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection`

Other Behaviors in the View do work, does someone know a solution to this?

Comment: Search engine brings me here. I have met the same issue too!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a solution but:
I'm not using Flyouts in my Windows 8.1 App, I'm using a UserControl on which I have added a `EventTriggerBehavior` as you did. And I get exactly the same Errormessage from VisualStudio at runtime.
As I am using a `RoutedEventHandler` this could cause the Problem as you use

```
EventHandler<object> Opening
```

as the Trigger for the Behavior. But that is just an idea of what is the problem.

**For me I have found an answer:**

I have changed the Type of my `RoutedEventHandler` to be just a normal `EventHandler`. And the Method inside the CodeBehind which triggers the `RoutedEventHandler` is invoked with only the sender, because I dont know how to convert `RoutedEventArgs` into `EventArgs`, but as long as I dont need the EventArgs it's not a problem.

You could also make a workaround by creating a UserControl with a Flyout Control and make the Opening Event public to the Page where you use it. Then you can add the `EventTriggerBehavior` to the UserControl and connect it to your custom `Opening` Event and you should get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely late answer here, but I had the same issue and came up with a solution after finding this post.

I just created a custom behavior specifically for flyouts, used like this.  `OpenActions` will execute when the flyout is opened, and `CloseActions` will execute when the flyout closes.  In this case, I wanted the bottom app bar to not be visible when the flyout was open.

```
<Flyout Placement="Full">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:FlyoutBehavior>
      <behaviors:FlyoutBehavior.OpenActions>
        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CommandBar}" />
      </behaviors:FlyoutBehavior.OpenActions>
      <behaviors:FlyoutBehavior.CloseActions>
        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CommandBar}" />
      </behaviors:FlyoutBehavior.CloseActions>
    </behaviors:FlyoutBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <Grid>
    ...
  </Grid>
</Flyout>
```

Code is here:

```
class FlyoutBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public void Attach(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        var flyout = associatedObject as FlyoutBase;

        if (flyout == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("FlyoutBehavior can be attached only to FlyoutBase");

        AssociatedObject = associatedObject;

        flyout.Opened += FlyoutOpened;
        flyout.Closed += FlyoutClosed;
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        var flyout = AssociatedObject as FlyoutBase;

        if (flyout != null)
        {
            flyout.Opened -= FlyoutOpened;
            flyout.Closed -= FlyoutClosed;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenActionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OpenActions", typeof(ActionCollection), typeof(FlyoutBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ActionCollection OpenActions
    {
        get { return GetValue(OpenActionsProperty) as ActionCollection; }
        set { SetValue(OpenActionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseActionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CloseActions", typeof(ActionCollection), typeof(FlyoutBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ActionCollection CloseActions
    {
        get { return GetValue(CloseActionsProperty) as ActionCollection; }
        set { SetValue(CloseActionsProperty, value); }
    }

    private void FlyoutOpened(object sender, object e)
    {
        foreach (IAction action in OpenActions)
        {
            action.Execute(AssociatedObject, null);
        }
    }

    private void FlyoutClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        foreach (IAction action in CloseActions)
        {
            action.Execute(AssociatedObject, null);
        }
    }

    public FlyoutBehavior()
    {
        OpenActions = new ActionCollection();
        CloseActions = new ActionCollection();
    }
}
```